# How to find Theta 1 and theta 2 inverse of the two line connecting

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

I'm doing the two axis arm robotics on the canvas which shown in the picture
as red to blue circle is theta 1 and than blue to yellow is theta 2
here i need to find joint pair of them which is inverse  as green and cyan circle is movable so i set according to inverse theta but seems not able to find inverse theta of them correctly
here angle are
theta1 = 80
theta2 = 50

and my math is bad so can't figure out how can i find their inverse
i found the angle using the axis of lines but it seems to be wrong i guess
these angle calculated using this function

```
function angle(cx, cy, ex, ey) {
    var dy = ey - cy;
    var dx = ex - cx;
    var theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx); // range (-PI, PI]
    theta *= 180 / Math.PI; // rads to degs, range (-180, 180]
    //if (theta < 0) theta = 360 + theta; // range [0, 360)
    return -theta;
  }
```

- A1 : 80 & A2 : 50
- A1' : 47.45904399010462 & A2' : 82.29636680333454

[image: IMG]

i.e. I made cyan circle move a bit on purpose to make yellow visible

1. red is base
2. blue,green is shoulder
3. yellow,cyan is tooltip

Comment: Your question might be more suited to [https://math.stackexchange.com/](https://math.stackexchange.com/) as its not directly programming related

Answer (score 0):

### Robot IK

Robotics IK is not just as simple as calculating joints, robots must move and driving a motor on a joint past its limits will hurt the robot, driving an arm through a table can hurt more than just the robot.

There is also a need to consider the stress and forces on the joints and mounts. How well the robot can position its self when approaching limits. There are many more considerations.

Therefor the solution below is strictly a visual solution using basic trig and vector maths.

### Ref

[image]

The diagram defines the naming I used. Points A,B,C,D, Lines AB, BD, AC, CD and red lines AD, BC. Angles are named ACD for angle at C,  ABD angle at B, etc. This naming is held in the example.

### Solve for D

This will position B and C to place D at a desired position. Point A is fixed and will not move.

This solution is only limited by the distance D is from A (length of line AD must be less the sum of lengths AB + BD)

#### Steps

D has been moves

Find distance from A to D

```
len = ((A.x - D.x) ** 2 + (A.y - D.y) ** 2) ** 0.5
```

Check that distance is within limit

```
// len1 is length first arm, len2 is second
if (len < len1 + len2) {
```

Find direction of line AD

```
   const dir = Math.atan2(D.y - A.y, D.x - A.x);
```

Find angle BAD

```
   const BAD = Math.acos((len2 * len2 - (len1 * len1 + len * len)) / (-2 * len1 * len));
```

The solution has been found, now we need only position B and C

The direction of AB is dir - BAD and for AC it is dir + BAD. The lengths are len1

```
   B.x = Math.cos(dir - BAD) * len1 + A.x;
   B.y = Math.sin(dir - BAD) * len1 + A.y;

   C.x = Math.cos(dir + BAD) * len1 + A.x;
   C.y = Math.sin(dir + BAD) * len1 + A.y;
```

### Solve for A

If the point A is moved this will solve points B, C with D fixed. This is the same solution as above but with points A, D swapped, as well as B, C swapped

### Solve for B or C

There are several ways to solve if the joints are moved, depending on constraints, as example I solve C using a different method than B.

#### Solve for B

The point B is moved but is constrained to the arm length AB, we also constrain the position of D to remain on the original line AD.

**Note** this is not a true IK solution

#### Steps

B has been moved.

Constrain B to the length of arm AB to best fit new position

Get AB as vector, normalize, and set length to `len1`

```
const dx = B.x - A.x;
const dy = B.y - A.y;
const dist = (dx * dx + dy * dy) ** 0.5;
const x = (dx / dist) * len1;
const y = (dy / dist) * len1;
```

Set the new position of B

```
B.x = A.x + x;
B.y = A.y + y;
```

Find the distance B is from the line AD. we create a new point F on the line AD that is closest to B

```
const vAx = D.x - A.x;
const vAy = D.y - A.y;
const vBx = B.x - A.x;
const vBy = B.y - A.y;

const u = (vAx * vBx + vAy * vBy) / (vAx * vAx + vAy * vAy);

// new Point F
F.x = A.x + u * vAx;
F.y = A.y + u * vAy;

// get dist
const x = F.x - B.x;
const y = F.y - B.y;

// the distance we are after
const dist = (x * x + y * y) ** 0.5;
```

If `dist` is greater than `len2` there is no solution. (there may be but that would pull B away from desired position and make some IK solutions erratic)

We now have two right triangles. Triangle AB, BF, FA and BD, DF, FB. There are two unknown lengths FA and FB. We have the rest so find the missing lengths

```
const lenFA = (len1 * len1 - dist) ** 0.5;
const lenFD = (len2 * len2 - dist) ** 0.5;
```

Use the vector from A to D. Normalize it and then scale to make its length `lenFA + lenFD` add this vector to A to get D.

To find C we use the right triangle AB, BF, FA and solve for the angle BAF which is the same as angle BAD.

```
const BAD = Math.asin(dist  / len1);
```

Find direction of AD and add angle BAD

```
const dirAD = Math.atan2(D.y - A.y, D.x - A.x) + BAD
```

Point C is `len1` from A in the direction dirAD

```
 C.x = Math.cos(dirAD) * len1 + A.x;
 C.y = Math.sin(dirAD) * len1 + A.y;
```

#### Solve for C

So sorry but SO is limiting length of answer 30K, and I am out of time. To see steps for solving for C see example function `solveForC`

### Example

The example is an interactive IK solution for the problem as I think you have defined.

There are 4 solvers. Which is use depends on which point you drag.

- Solve B, C, fix D when moving A. This is the default solver.
- Solve B, C, fix A when moving D. Reverse of above
- Solve B, D, fix A when moving C.
- Solve C, D, fix A and constrain D to line AD

The lengths of arms AB, and AC are set the the length if white line L1-L2 and BD and CD are set to the length of line L3-L4

**Note** Code of interest is at the top of the snippet, and I have marked code that is not directly related to the answer with a comment.

**Note**  I made an mistake in IK solution of joint B. If you drag joint B and the length of the second arm is longer than the length of the first arm, the solver fails to detect the limit. The result is that arm length BD is incorrect. But as most of this is a guess I will leave it up to you how to deal with error.

**Best used as full page**

```js
setTimeout(() => { 

    // points and lines as in diagram of answer
    const A = new Vec2(-200,200);
    const B = new Vec2(-100, 0);
    const C = new Vec2( 100, 0);
    const D = new Vec2( 100, -100);
    const AB = new Line2(A, B), BA = new Line2(B, A);
    const AC = new Line2(A, C), CA = new Line2(C, A);
    const BD = new Line2(B, D), DB = new Line2(D, B);
    const CD = new Line2(C, D), DC = new Line2(D, C);
    
    // internal lines
    const AD = new Line2(A, D), DA = new Line2(D, A);
    const BC = new Line2(B, C), CB = new Line2(B, C);
    
    // points to define arm lengths len1, len2
    const L1 = new Vec2(-300, -200);
    const L2 = new Vec2( -50, -200);
    const L3 = new Vec2(  50, -200);
    const L4 = new Vec2( 300, -200);    
    const L12 = new Line2(L1, L2);
    const L34 = new Line2(L3, L4);
    
    var len1 = L12.length;  // length of first Arms from A to B or C
    var len2 = L34.length;  // length of second Arms from D to B or C
    
    // A set of predefined working vectors to prevent GC thrashing
    const v1 = new Vec2();
    const v2 = new Vec2();
    const v3 = new Vec2();
    
    function solveForA() { // D is Fixed
        const dist = AD.length;
        if (dist < len1 + len2 && dist > Math.abs(len1 - len2)) {
            const dir = AD.direction;
            const BAD = Math.triCosPheta(len1, dist, len2);
            AB.asVec(v1).direction = dir - Math.acos(BAD);
            v1.length = len1;
            B.init(v1.add(A));
            AC.asVec(v1).direction = dir + Math.acos(BAD);
            v1.length = len1;
            C.init(v1.add(A));
            error = false; 
        } else { error = true }
        
    }
    
    function solveForD() { // A is fixed
        const dist = DA.length;
        if (dist < len1 + len2 && dist > Math.abs(len1 - len2)) {
            const dir = DA.direction;
            const ADB = Math.triCosPheta(len2, dist, len1);
            DB.asVec(v1).direction = dir + Math.acos(ADB);
            v1.length = len2;
            B.init(v1.add(D));
            DC.asVec(v1).direction = dir - Math.acos(ADB);
            v1.length = len2;
            C.init(v1.add(D));
            error = false; 
        } else { error = true }
    }
    
    function solveForC() {  // A is fixed, C Best fit
        AC.asVec(v1);
        v1.length = len1;
        C.init(v1.add(A));
        CD.asVec(v1);
        v1.length = len2;
        D.init(v1.add(C));
        const dist = AD.length;
        const DAC = Math.triCosPheta(len1, dist, len2);
        v1.initPolar(AD.direction - Math.acos(DAC), len1);
        B.init(v1.add(A));
    }    
    
    function solveForB() {  // A is fixed, D constrained to line AD
        AB.asVec(v1);
        v1.length = len1;
        B.init(v1.add(A));
        
        // REF the closest point on line AD from B is F
        const opp = AD.distanceLineFromVec(B);  // length line BF 
        if (opp < len2) {                       // is there a solution
            const opp2 = opp * opp;             // length squared
            const adjA = (len1 * len1 - opp2) ** 0.5; // length of line AF
            const adjD = (len2 * len2 - opp2) ** 0.5; // length of line DF
            
            AD.asVec(v1).length = adjA + adjD;  // vector along AD with length of line AD
            D.init(v1.add(A));
            
            const dir = AD.direction;
            C.init(v1.initPolar(dir + Math.asin(opp  / len1), len1).add(A));
            
            error = false;
        } else { error = true }
    
    }    
    
/*==========================================================================================================
     Here on down UI, and all the support code 
*/
    requestAnimationFrame(update); 
    
    solveForA();
    
    const refRes = 512;
    var scale = 1;
    const mousePos = new Vec2();
    var w = 0, h = 0, cw = 0, ch = 0;
    var frame = 0, error = false;
    var blk = "#000", wht = "#FFF", red = "#F00", black = "#000";
    const ui = Vecs2([A, B, C, D, L1, L2, L3, L4])
    function update(timer){
        frame ++;
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
        if (w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight){
            cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
            ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
            scale = Math.min(w / refRes, h / refRes);
        } else {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        }
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        //mouse.forElement(canvas);
        mousePos.init(mouse);
        mousePos.x = (mousePos.x - canvas.width / 2) / scale;
        mousePos.y = (mousePos.y -canvas.height / 2) / scale;
        mousePos.button = mouse.button;
        ctx.font = "24px Arial black"
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale,canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
        const nearest = ui.dragable(mousePos, 20);
        if (ui.dragging) {
            if (nearest === L1 || nearest === L2 || nearest === L3 || nearest === L4) {
                if (nearest === L1) { L1.y = L2.y }
                else if (nearest === L2) { L2.y = L1.y }
                else if (nearest === L3) { L3.y = L4.y }
                else if (nearest === L4) { L4.y = L3.y }
                len1 = L12.length;
                len2 = L34.length;
                solveForA();
            } else if(nearest === A) {
                solveForA();
            } else if(nearest === D) {
                solveForD()
            } else if(nearest === C) {
                solveForC()
            } else if(nearest === B) {
                solveForB()
            }
        
        }
        if (nearest) {
            canvas.style.cursor = ui.dragging ? "none" : "move";
            nearest.draw(ctx, "#F00", 2, 4);
            if (nearest.isLine2) {
                nearest.nearestOnLine(mousePos, onLine).draw(ctx, "#FFF", 2, 2)
            }
        } else {
            canvas.style.cursor = "default";
        }

        ui.mark(ctx, wht, 1, 4);
        ui.mark(ctx, wht, 1, 14);
        L12.draw(ctx,wht,2)
        L34.draw(ctx,wht,2)
        
        ctx.fillStyle = wht;
        ctx.fillText("L1", L1.x, L1.y - 16)
        ctx.fillText("L2", L2.x, L2.y - 16)
        ctx.fillText("L3", L3.x, L3.y - 16)
        ctx.fillText("L4", L4.x, L4.y - 16)


        AD.draw(ctx, red, 1)
        BC.draw(ctx, red, 1)


        AB.draw(ctx, blk, 4)
        AC.draw(ctx, blk, 4)
        BD.draw(ctx, blk, 4)  
        CD.draw(ctx, blk, 4)  
        
        A.draw(ctx, blk, 4, 8);
        C.draw(ctx, blk, 4, 8);
        B.draw(ctx, blk, 4, 8);
        D.draw(ctx, blk, 4, 8);

        A.draw(ctx, "#F00", 4, 4);
        C.draw(ctx, "#0A0", 4, 4);
        B.draw(ctx, "#00F", 4, 4);
        D.draw(ctx, "#0FF", 4, 4);
        
        ctx.fillStyle = blk;
        ctx.fillText("A", A.x, A.y + 32)
        ctx.fillText("B", B.x - 26, B.y)
        ctx.fillText("C", C.x + 26, C.y)
        ctx.fillText("D", D.x, D.y - 16)

        ctx.font = "16px Arial";
        drawAngle(B, BA, BD, 30, B.add(Vec2.Vec(-160, -50), Vec2.Vec()), ctx, blk, 2);
        drawAngle(C, CA, CD, 30, C.add(Vec2.Vec(160, 0), Vec2.Vec()), ctx, blk, 2);

        blk = error ? red : black;
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
      
    }
}, 0);

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const mouse  = {x: 0, y: 0, ox: 0, oy: 0, button: false, callback: undefined}
function mouseEvents(e) {
    const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
    mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
}
["down", "up", "move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouseEvents));
var SPEED = 0.05;
//canvas.addEventListener("mouseover",() => SPEED = 0);
//canvas.addEventListener("mouseout",() => SPEED = 0.05);
Math.EPSILON = 1e-6;
Math.isSmall = val => Math.abs(val) < Math.EPSILON;
Math.isUnit = u => !(u < 0 || u > 1);
Math.uClamp = u => u <= 0 ? 0 : u >= 1 ? 1 : u; // almost 2* faster than Math.min, Math.Max method
Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
Math.rand = (m, M) => Math.random() * (M - m) + m;
Math.randI = (m, M) => Math.random() * (M - m) + m | 0;
Math.rad2Deg = r => r * 180 / Math.PI;
Math.triCosPheta = (a, b, c) => (c * c - (a * a + b * b)) / (-2 * a * b); // return the cosine of the angle pheta of a triangle given length of sides a,b,c. Pheta is the angle opposite the length c
Math.triLenC = (a, b, p) => Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b - 2 * a * b * Math.cos(p)); // return the length of side C given the length of two sides a,b and the angle p opposite the edge C
Math.symbols = {};
Math.symbols.degrees = "°";
/* export {Vec2, Line2} */ // this should be a module
var temp;
function Vec2(x = 0, y = (temp = x, x === 0 ? (x = 0 , 0) : (x = x.x, temp.y))) { this.x = x; this.y = y }
Vec2.Vec = (x, y) => ({x, y}); // Vec2 like
Vec2.prototype = {
    isVec2: true,
    init(x, y = (temp = x, x = x.x, temp.y)) { this.x = x; this.y = y; return this }, // assumes x is a Vec2 if y is undefined
    initPolar(dir, length = (temp = dir, dir = dir.x, temp.y)) { this.x = Math.cos(dir) * length; this.y = Math.sin(dir) * length; return this },
    toPolar(res = this) {
        const dir = this.direction, len = this.length;
        res.x = dir;
        res.y = length;
        return res;
    },
    zero() { this.x = this.y = 0; return this },
    initUnit(dir) { this.x = Math.cos(dir); this.y = Math.sin(dir); return this },
    copy() { return new Vec2(this) },
    equal(v) { return (this.x - v.x) === 0 && (this.y - v.y) === 0 },
    isUnits() { return Math.isUnit(this.x) && Math.isUnit(this.y) },
    add(v, res = this) { res.x = this.x + v.x; res.y = this.y + v.y; return res },
    addScaled(v, scale, res = this) { res.x = this.x + v.x * scale; res.y = this.y + v.y * scale; return res },
    sub(v, res = this) { res.x = this.x - v.x; res.y = this.y - v.y; return res },
    scale(val, res = this) { res.x = this.x * val; res.y = this.y * val; return res },
    invScale(val, res = this) { res.x = this.x / val; res.y = this.y / val; return res },
    dot(v) { return this.x * v.x + this.y * v.y },
    uDot(v, div) { return (this.x * v.x + this.y * v.y) / div },
    cross(v) { return this.x * v.y - this.y * v.x },
    uCross(v, div) { return (this.x * v.y - this.y * v.x) / div },
    get direction() { return Math.atan2(this.y, this.x) },
    set direction(dir) { this.initPolar(dir, this.length) },
    get length() { return this.lengthSqr ** 0.5 },
    set length(l) { this.scale(l / this.length) },
    get lengthSqr() { return this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y },
    set lengthSqr(lSqr) { this.scale(lSqr ** 0.5 / this.length) },
    distanceFrom(vec) { return ((this.x - vec.x) ** 2 + (this.y - vec.y) ** 2) ** 0.5 },
    distanceSqrFrom(vec) { return ((this.x - vec.x) ** 2 + (this.y - vec.y) ** 2) },
    directionTo(vec) { return Math.atan2(vec.y - this.y, vec.x - this.x) },
    normalize(res = this) { return this.invScale(this.length, res) },
    rotate90CW(res = this) {
        const y = this.x;
        res.x = -this.y;
        res.y = y;
        return res;
    },
    angleTo(vec) {
        const xa = this.x, ya = this.y;
        const xb = vec.x, yb = vec.y;
        const l = ((xa * xa + ya * ya) * (xb * xb + yb * yb)) ** 0.5;
        var ang = 0;
        if (l !== 0) {
            ang = Math.asin((xa  * yb  - ya * xb) / l);
            if (xa  * xb  + ya * yb < 0) { return (ang < 0 ? -Math.PI: Math.PI) - ang }
        }
        return ang;
    },
    drawFrom(v, ctx, col = ctx.strokeStyle, lw = ctx.lineWidth, scale = 1) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = col;
        ctx.lineWidth = lw;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(v.x, v.y);
        ctx.lineTo(v.x + this.x * scale, v.y + this.y * scale);
        ctx.stroke();
    },
    draw(ctx, col = ctx.strokeStyle, lw = ctx.lineWidth, size = 4) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = col;
        ctx.lineWidth = lw;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, size, 0, Math.TAU);
        ctx.stroke();
    },
    path(ctx, size) {
        ctx.moveTo(this.x + size, this.y);
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, size, 0, Math.TAU);
    },
    toString(digits = 3) { return "{x: " + this.x.toFixed(digits) + ", y: " + this.y.toFixed(digits) + "}" },
};
function Vecs2(vecsOrLength) {
    const vecs2 = Object.assign([], Vecs2.prototype);
    if (Array.isArray(vecsOrLength)) { vecs2.push(...vecsOrLength) }
    else if (vecsOrLength && vecsOrLength >= 1) {
        while (vecsOrLength-- > 0) { vecs2.push(new Vec2()) }
    }
    return vecs2;
}
Vecs2.prototype = {
    isVecs2: true,
    nearest(vec, maxDist = Infinity, tolerance = 1) { // max for argument semantic, used as semantic min in function
        var found;
        for (const v of this) {
            const dist = v.distanceFrom(vec);
            if (dist < maxDist) {
                if (dist <= tolerance) { return v }
                maxDist = dist;
                found = v;
            }
        }
        return found;
    },
    copy() {
        var idx = 0;
        const copy = Vecs2(this.length);
        for(const p of this) { copy[idx++].init(p) }
        return copy;
    },
    uniformTransform(rMat, pMat, res = this) {
        var idx = 0;
        for(const p of this) {  p.uniformTransform(rMat, pMat, res[idx++]) }
    },
    mark(ctx, col = ctx.strokeStyle, lw = ctx.lineWidth, size = 4) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = col;
        ctx.lineWidth = lw;
        ctx.beginPath();
        for (const p of this) { p.path(ctx, size) }
        ctx.stroke();
    },    
    draw(ctx, close = false, col = ctx.strokeStyle, lw = ctx.lineWidth) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = col;
        ctx.lineWidth = lw;
        ctx.beginPath();
        for (const p of this) { ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y) }
        close && ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    },
    path(ctx, first = true) {
        for (const p of this) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
            } else { ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y) }
        }
    },
    dragable(mouse, maxDist = Infinity, tolerance = 1) {
        var near;
        if (this.length) {
            if (!this.dragging) {
                if (!this.offset) { this.offset = new Vec2() }
                near = this.nearest(this.offset.init(mouse), maxDist, tolerance); // mouse may not be a Vec2
                if (near && mouse.button) {
                    this.dragging = near;
                    this.offset.init(near).sub(mouse);
                }
            }
            if (this.dragging) {
                near = this.dragging;
                if (mouse.button) { this.dragging.init(mouse).add(this.offset) }
                else { this.dragging = undefined }
            }
        }
        return near;
    }
}
function Line2(p1 = new Vec2(), p2 = (temp = p1, p1 = p1.p1 ? p1.p1 : p1, temp.p2 ? temp.p2 : new Vec2())) {
    this.p1 = p1;
    this.p2 = p2;
}
Line2.prototype = {
    isLine2: true,
    init(p1, p2 = (temp = p1, p1 = p1.p1, temp.p2)) { this.p1.init(p1); this.p2.init(p2) },
    copy() { return new Line2(this) },
    asVec(res = new Vec2()) { return this.p2.sub(this.p1, res) },
    unitDistOn(u, res = new Vec2()) { return this.p2.sub(this.p1, res).scale(u).add(this.p1) },
    unitDistanceOn(u, res = new Vec2()) { return this.p2.sub(this.p1, res).scale(u).add(this.p1) },
    distAlong(dist, res = new Vec2()) { return this.p2.sub(this.p1, res).uDot(res, res.length).add(this.p1) },
    distanceAlong(dist, res = new Vec2()) { return this.p2.sub(this.p1, res).scale(dist / res.length).add(this.p1) },
    get length() { return this.lengthSqr ** 0.5 },
    get lengthSqr() { return (this.p1.x - this.p2.x) ** 2 + (this.p1.y - this.p2.y) ** 2 },
    get direction() { return this.asVec(wV2).direction },
    translate(vec, res = this) {
        this.p1.add(vec, res.p1);
        this.p2.add(vec, res.p2);
        return res;
    },
    reflect(line, u, res = line) {
        this.asVec(wV2).normalize();
        line.asVec(wV1);
        line.unitDistOn(u, res.p1);
        const d = wV1.uDot(wV2, 0.5);
        wV3.init(wV2.x * d - wV1.x, wV2.y * d - wV1.y);
        res.p1.add(wV3.scale(1 - u), res.p2);
        return res;
    },
    reflectAsUnitVec(line, u, res = new Vec2()) {
        this.asVec(res).normalize();
        line.asVec(wV1);
        return res.scale(wV1.uDot(res, 0.5)).sub(wV1).normalize()
    },
    angleTo(line) { return this.asVec(wV1).angleTo(line.asVec(wV2)) },
    translateNormal(amount, res = this) {
        this.asVec(wV1).rot90CW().length = -amount;
        this.translate(wV1, res);
        return res;
    },
    distanceNearestVec(vec) { // WARNING!! distanceLineFromVec is (and others are) dependent on vars used in this function
        return this.asVec(wV1).uDot(vec.sub(this.p1, wV2), wV1.length);
    },
    unitNearestVec(vec) { // WARNING!! distanceLineFromVec is (and others are) dependent on vars used in this function
        return this.asVec(wV1).uDot(vec.sub(this.p1, wV2), wV1.lengthSqr);
    },
    nearestOnLine(vec, res = new Vec2()) { return this.p1.addScaled(wV1, this.unitNearestVec(vec), res) },
    nearestOnSegment(vec, res = new Vec2()) { return this.p1.addScaled(wV1, Math.uClamp(this.unitNearestVec(vec)), res) },
    distanceLineFromVec(vec) { return this.nearestOnLine(vec, wV1).sub(vec).length },
    distanceSegmentFromVec(vec) { return this.nearestOnSegment(vec, wV1).sub(vec).length },
    unitInterceptsLine(line, res = new Vec2()) {  // segments
        this.asVec(wV1);
        line.asVec(wV2);
        const c = wV1.cross(wV2);
        if (Math.isSmall(c)) { return }
        wV3.init(this.p1).sub(line.p1);
        res.init(wV1.uCross(wV3, c), wV2.uCross(wV3, c));
        return res;
    },
    unitInterceptsCircle(point, radius, res = new Vec2()) {
        this.asVec(wV1);
        var b = -2 * this.p1.sub(point, wV2).dot(wV1);
        const c = 2 * wV1.lengthSqr;
        const d = (b * b - 2 * c * (wV2.lengthSqr - radius * radius)) ** 0.5
        if (isNaN(d)) { return }
        return res.init((b - d) / c, (b + d) / c);
    },
    draw(ctx, col = ctx.strokeStyle, lw = ctx.lineWidth) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = col;
        ctx.lineWidth = lw;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(this.p1.x, this.p1.y);
        ctx.lineTo(this.p2.x, this.p2.y);
        ctx.stroke();
    },
    path(ctx) {
        ctx.moveTo(this.p1.x, this.p1.y);
        ctx.lineTo(this.p2.x, this.p2.y);
    },
    toString(digits = 3) { return "{ p1: " + this.p1.toString(digits) + ", p2: "  + this.p2.toString(digits) + "}" },
};

const wV1 = new Vec2(), wV2 = new Vec2(), wV3 = new Vec2(); // pre allocated work vectors used by Line2 functions
const wVA1 = new Vec2(), wVA2 = new Vec2(), wVA3 = new Vec2(); // pre allocated work vectors 
const wVL1 = new Vec2(), wVL2 = new Vec2(), wVL3 = new Vec2(); // pre allocated work vectors used by Line2Array functions
const wL1 = new Line2(), wL2 = new Line2(), wL3 = new Line2(); // pre allocated work lines
function drawLable(text, from, to, ctx, col = ctx.strokeStyle, lw = ctx.lineWidth) {
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    ctx.lineWidth = lw;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(from.x, from.y);
    ctx.lineTo(to.x, to.y);
    ctx.stroke();   
    const w = ctx.measureText(text).width;
    var offset = 8;
    if (from.x < to.x) { ctx.fillText(text, to.x + offset + w / 2, to.y) }
    else { ctx.fillText(text, to.x - offset - w / 2, to.y) }
}
function drawAngle(pos, lineA, lineB, radius, lablePos, ctx, col = ctx.strokeStyle, lw = ctx.lineWidth) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    ctx.lineWidth = lw;
    const from = lineA.direction;
    const angle = lineA.angleTo(lineB);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, radius, from, from + angle, angle < 0);
    ctx.stroke();   
    drawLable(
        Math.rad2Deg(angle).toFixed(2) + Math.symbols.degrees,
        Vec2.Vec(
            pos.x + Math.cos(from + angle / 2) * radius, 
            pos.y + Math.sin(from + angle / 2) * radius
        ),
        lablePos,
        ctx,
        col,
        lw / 2,
    );
}
```

```css
canvas { 
    position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; 
    background: #4D8;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I gotta be honest, I do not understand what you are trying to achieve, but what about

```
A1  = 80  and  A2  = 50
A1' = 50  and  A2' = 80
```

Basically, if `theta1` is the angle between the `[red, dark-blue]` edge and the horizontal line (the x-axis), and `theta2` is the angle between the `[dark-blue, yellow]` edge and the horizontal line (the x-axis), then

```
theta1' = angle between [red, green] edge and x-axis
theta2' = angle between [red, light-blue] edge and x-axis
```

in order to complete the configuration to a rhombus:

```
theta1' = theta2
theta2' = theta1
```